# Talend - How make a context of a tMap component

Tags: talend

I have a Talend Job that currently does the following:

```
Input csv (tFileInputDelimited) --> tMap --> Output csv(tFileInputDelimited)
```

The goal of my job, is keep a value from the tMap, and use it to rename the output file.

I've tried to use a context and specify the row and the column I want to use, but it didn't work.

I'm a beginner, I use talend during an intership, I started 6 years ago, so I don't know many things ^^

Thank you for you future help !

Comment: `I tryed use a context and specify the row and the column I want to use` meaning? Please provide more info what you have done so far.

Comment: For exemple, I take "row1.Column1" . So to catch this data I use a context with the value : row1.Column1 . And I use it later in my tFileOutputDelimited with just a context.name

Comment: Please clarify the goal. Which value should be kept? With your idea, only the value of the last row will be in the context variable.

Comment: I try to catch a number from a file, and use it to rename an other file : "number.csv"  One of my file column contain the same value each row, and it's this value ( a number ) that I want to use.

Comment: Please show a picture of your ETL process and the contents of tMap.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found a solution with tflowToIterate and tFixedFlowInput, you can select only one cell of the tMap. Then I can rename my file without probleme. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `tJavaRow` to capture the value from the flow and assign it to the variable, the code will be like this :

```
// get the value of wanted_field of the id 40
if (input.id == 40) context.myvar = input.wanted_field
```

Your job will look like this:

```
Input csv (tFileInputDelimited) --> tJavaRow --> tMap --> Output csv(tFileInputDelimited)
```